# HttpServerChannel could not be found

Tags: c#, http, .net-remoting

I want to make a remoting application.

On my server application, I added System.Runtime.Remoting library.
And on my source code, I wrote:

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;
```

And inside my class, I wrote:

```
HttpServerChannel channel = new HttpServerChannel(1111);
```

But then I got error message:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpServerChannel' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem? I want to create an object from HttpServerChannel class.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be ok, what you did. Which .NET Framework Version are you using?

Comment: I use .NET version 4.
I found my friends have the same problem with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the settings of your server application project in Visual Studio if the Target Framework is set to **.NET Framework 4**.

If the Target Framework is set to **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile**, then change it to target framework named above.

The Assemblies in the Client Profile doesn´t include the server channels.

Note:
If you just start developing distributed applications with .NET, then you should use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), cause .NET Remoting has been deprecated.

Comment: ah. thank you.
It was in Client Profile, so that caused my problem. Now it's solved.